# how do I fix some versioning issue when compiling C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to compile on Linux the file at http://sourceforge.net/projects/desr/files/Release/desr-0.9.tgz/download .

When I run ./configure, everything works smoothly, until I type make.
Then I get the following errors:

```
In file included from ./string.h:33,
                 from HtmlTokenizer.cpp:24:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:76: error: ‘::memchr’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:77: error: ‘::memcmp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:78: error: ‘::memcpy’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:79: error: ‘::memmove’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:80: error: ‘::memset’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:81: error: ‘::strcat’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:82: error: ‘::strcmp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:83: error: ‘::strcoll’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:84: error: ‘::strcpy’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:85: error: ‘::strcspn’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:86: error: ‘::strerror’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:87: error: ‘::strlen’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:88: error: ‘::strncat’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:89: error: ‘::strncmp’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:90: error: ‘::strncpy’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:91: error: ‘::strspn’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:92: error: ‘::strtok’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:93: error: ‘::strxfrm’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:94: error: ‘::strchr’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:95: error: ‘::strpbrk’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:96: error: ‘::strrchr’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.4/cstring:97: error: ‘::strstr’ has not been declared
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Here is g++ --version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is

```
 #include <cstring>
```

the g++ compiler should put the  declarations it itself includes into the std:: AND the global namespaces. It looks for some reason as if it is not doing that. Try replacing one instance of strcpy with std::strcpy .

Comment: The Makefile could be feeding a compiler flag that avoids the inclusion of the standard include paths.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem. In my case, the order of header file inclusion were as follows

```
#include <string> // for string class
#include <cstring> // for memcpy()
```

With this, I ran into above errors that you mention with gcc 4.6.3.

Switching the order of includes worked..

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause of this issue is that you have managed to somewhere get a `#include <cstring>` inside a namespace block.

This results in setting the `#define` for the include guard, stopping you from re-importing it anywhere else, but in the meantime loading all the symbols into your namespace instead of into global scope where they belong.

I sometimes make this mistake when I'm trying to put inline template definitions in a separate file from their declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is quite old, I will just add to the @Daniels answer.
For me the error was caused because of including the `<cstring>` in source file after a header that had a class definition not terminated with a `;`.